# Oracle Incremental Checksum Crypto for Security

Tags: java, oracle, hash, cryptography, checksum

I have a unique problem to solve.
I have a legacy java application which connects to an Oracle RDBMS. There are all sorts of queries and DMLs scattered over in the application - Inserts, Update, Delete and of course selects. It uses JBC (`Preparedstatement`), though one recently added lodule uses JPA.

I have a requirement to add a protection layer / logic to the application / Database whereby if any user (could even be A DBA or an OS root user) tries to modify the data (updates, inserts or deletes) bypassing the app, we are able to identify the operation as part of an audit.

Audit trail seemed to be the go to thing here, except that we cannot even trust the OS root user and thus a guy having DBA and root access can easily modify the data and remove the trace of it in the audit trails.

I was thinking to implement a cyclic crypto kind of algorithm on the sensitive tables so that on every DML executed by the application, a crypto / hash is introduced and it is incremental so that any change is easily caught by doing an audit using the application.

In theory, it seems feasible except that it might get tricky because after every DML we would potentially need to recalculate the hash / checksum of a number of subsequent records and this might overburden the application / database.

Is this a feasible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that computing a hash of every updated row of data will impose a burden on the system. Are you going to also validate that hash before changes are submitted to the database to ensure nothing has been changed outside the application? That's even more overhead, and a lot more custom code for your application. It also wouldn't help you identify who modified the data, or when, only that it had been updated outside of the app. Using a database trigger wouldn't work, as they are easily disabled and aren't capable of modifying the same table that calls them (you'd need a separate hash table with an entry for every row of data in every table you wanted to monitor). Auditing is still your best way to go, as it wouldn't require any modification to your app or your data schemas.

You have a couple of options in regards to auditing, depending on the version of Oracle you're using. If you're using 12c or later, you can use Unified Auditing, which has its own set of permissions and roles to allow separation of duties (i.e. normal DBA from security admin). Even in older versions you can put an update/delete audit on the actual audit trail table, so that any attempt to modify the data will itself leave a fingerprint.

Lastly, you can use a tool like Splunk, Elastic Search, syslog, or Oracle's Database Audit Vault or some other file monitoring solution to centralize your audit records to another system as they are created by the database - making them inaccessible to the DBA or local sys admin. This will take some work by your DBA and/or sysadmin to configure in the first place, but can go a long way to securing your audit data.

All that said, sooner or later you're going to *have* to trust two people: the sys admin and the DBA. If you can't trust them then you are in deep, deep trouble.

Comment: The first two options that you mention - separation of duties and / or audit on audit tables. Is there any doc available to explain these more? Does it mean, any modification on audit tables would leave a cyclic fingerprint? The DBA could still disable those temporarily right?

Comment: Also, even if I use a tool like elasticsearch or syslog, the DBA / sysadmin could still disable that temporarily?

Comment: In general there's no way to prevent the DBA from interfering with the system in some way; in the end there has to be someone with privileges to update the software, start and stop services, etc., which usually requires full sysdba access. You have no choice but to trust that person fully. That said, even disabling auditing is itself an auditable event that would leave a trace in the trail, so there's no way to escape detection completely. You might not know what was done while auditing was turned off, but someone would still have to explain why auditing was turned off.

Comment: Separation of duties with Oracle 12c is well documented. See here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/administrative-privileges-and-job-role-separation-12cr1.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 20c has [blockchain tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-E7151628-AF04-48D4-9CB4-F72417AFC391).  Version 20c is currently only available in Oracle's cloud, but it will probably be available on-premise in a few months.